# What transformations to go from top-down fisheye to occupancy (ground texture)

Tags: computer-vision

My goal is to warp a top-down fisheye view to end up with a flat square 'texture' that could be applied to a flat plane and would represent the 'real' floor eg a 1024x1024 texture would map to a 4 meter by 4 meter of floor in the room (ignore the other 'items'). Or even 2 meter by 2 meter around the center.

In other words I just want to flatten the floor in the image and project it 'orthographically' so that each one of those checkerboard squares is exactly the same size.  If the whole floor was covered in checkers, with no other items, my output would be flat checkerboard crop of 4 meters by 4 meters.

camera is [imx 219 200 FOV](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07Z2T2LBH) about 1.3 meters off the ground pointing straight down. (well if it were pointing exactly straight down the red down would be on the green dot)

I am looking for python opencv implementation, but if someone at least knows what it is that I need to do/measure to achieve it, it will be super helpful.

I have not seen any other examples of fisheye pointing downward, and more than just the 'straight lines' I need the 'orthographic' projection where all squares are same size regardless of distance from camera.

[image]

My concern is that after fisheye correction, the squares toward the center will be 'larger' than at the side, even if the lines are vertically and horizontally parallel.  eg, if fisheye 'fixes' this image, will all the squares be same size, or will just lines be parallel?

[image]

for example the following would not be acceptible, even if all the lines are parallel:

[image]

After calibration, I end up with this:
[image]

In the image above, I copy-pasted the closest black square and pasted it along each row so you can see how the squares get smaller as they get farther away. I need to know how to correct that.

Comment: See the [OpenCV page on lens calibration](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html).

Comment: @TimWescott is regular camera calibration same as fisheye calibration? if so why does cv have fisheye calibration module?  what kind of transform will make not only the lines straight but equally spaced?

Comment: The OpenCV method should also work for a fisheye lens, but you may need more terms.  That method works just fine for the 110-degree FOV cameras we're using, which is pretty close to what you're using.  And yes -- for a surface that's parallel to the camera's focal plane, the whole **point** of getting $x$ and $y$ correct is that straight lines will be straight, etc.

Comment: @TimWescott i understand straight lines straight, but what i need is strait lines spaced out the same.  ie the image to 'expand'  so checkerboard not only has straight lines, but all of them are eg 30 pixels square, whether they are close to center or far at side.  This is not a usual fisheye which retains 'converging lines'.  it's orthographic, for 'mapping'.

Comment: I guess I thought squares further away would be smaller, but maybe it's not true as long as plane is parallel  to camera (camera pointing straight down)

Comment: The whole point of camera calibration is that you're mapping what's happening on the sensor to what's happening down there.  The OpenCV definitely calibrates such that a surface parallel to the sensor "looks right".  Note, however, that I'm being very careful in my use of "parallel" -- without that, all bets are off.

Comment: @TimWescott the thing is, for a pinhole camera, the image will just be proportionally smaller.  But once you have a lens warping the image, just 'eliminating curvature' cannot preserve '3d space' points mapped orthographically to the plane. For example, if we flattened the fisheye image in the middle of a large flat area (eg the desert) the plane that is visible is 'miles' long, only limited by curvature of Earth.  So something is missing to map it to equally sized squares but I don't know what it is, and what constraints there are.

Comment: Wow.  So -- don't try what you've been directed to!  Just keep asking questions, and rejecting the answers!

Comment: @TimWescott haha, sorry to offend you man. It's not first time I've calibrated a camera before.  It's just first time I've had purpose of occupancy mapping directly from top-down fisheye.  As I explained, it's physically impossible for a camera with fov > 180 over an arbitrarily wide checkered surface to map to a an image with square checkers containing all the checkers that were in view. So I'm looking for someone who understands how to manage the transform and set up the cutoffs and describe the limits based on some understandable theory.

Comment: @TimWescott I updated with a result after successful fisheye calibration.  the checkerboards I calibrated with are all straightened, and you can see in that image the table straight, where it was curved in the original. but sure enough, the farther squares are smaller than the closer ones.

Comment: Try using their equations, but extend the number of terms.  Or see if there's a better curve to fit to than a polynomial (arctan?).  For any FOV less than 180 degrees, there should be a correction.

Comment: @TimWescott Yeah, so I think I need to define a limit in pixels or cm, so like "based on height from ground and calibrated perspective, identify what part of the image corresponds to 4.096 meter square  and map that to an 'image texture' of 4096x4096 where each pixel is 1mm.   So a lot of detail is lost near the center, and there will be some interpolation near the edge, but the if camera were above a 4m square checkerboard, you'd get a perfectly distributed checkerboard texture (though blurryer at edges). This is what I mean by orthographic.  Cameras by nature are perspective, not ortho.

Comment: @TimWescott I just want to say thanks.  You were right about what to do.  In my head I realized that something wasn't going to work since image was >180 FOV and truly trying to map even eg 170 FOV would have been absurd because of not enought pixels and >180 would mean 'upside down image'.  What I didn't realize is that the regular process would just crop out a small 90 FOV rather than actually warp the whole input image onto a plane.  So anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Allright well, @TimeWescott was essentially correct about what I had to do, though the theory took some investigation and thought before I realized what the parts to the puzzle are, and the inherent limitation.

The key point is that you CANNOT map a >180 FOV image to a flat texture, of course! This is because after 180, you cross the horizon and are now mapping the 'ceiling'.

Also my first attempt at calibration with printed board was not as accurate as I needed.  I re calibrated using my 27 in monitor as the checkerboard and moving the camera around instead.

The reality is that OpenCV does do the right thing.  Essentially it will just crop at some FOV like 90 but it will give an image that is not only 'straight lines' but lines 'equally spaced'.  It will stretch the out to be the same size.

So with this code I get the map I need:

```
DIM=(1232,1232)
K=np.array([
  [418.06635, 0.0,     621.82551], 
  [0.0,     418.06635, 610.67209], 
  [0.0,       0.0,       1.0    ]])
D=np.array([[-0.02120], [-0.00141], [-0.00050], [0.00000]])

map1, map2 = cv2.fisheye.initUndistortRectifyMap(K, D, np.eye(3), K, DIM, cv2.CV_16SC2)
img = cv2.remap(img, map1, map2, interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
```

[image]

So the most one could 'hope' for as far as mapping would be FOV 179 because FOV180 would map to an 'infinitely large image'. So OpenCV just chops it off at whatever FOV allows a full image to show, without adding 'black pixels' to handle stretch.  So basically whatever is inside a circle representing about about FOV 90 gets unwarped and undistrorted and mapped to flat 'floor texture' as I need.

You could theoretically do some kind of separate unwarp of the top half to get a ceiling texture with a big empty hole in the middle, but bottom line, you cannot map more than 179 FOV to a ground texture and reality is closer to 90 fov with quite a bit of blurriness toward the edges already (meaning it's not worth playing around with warping settings since that's already the largest 'useful' floor texture you'll get)